# You earned -30 reputation today

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, wording, achievements-dialog

> You earned -30 reputation today on ...

The above doesn't sound right to me. It appears as the tooltip in the "recent achievements" dialog:

> [image]

Can this please be changed to something like:

> You lost 30 reputation today on ...

Comment: But that just sounds so ... *negative*... ;)

Comment: I guess changing `earned` to `gained` makes it go both ways better...

Comment: @Werner not sure, for both I expect positive number to follow. Not a native English speaker though, so I might be wrong.

Comment: When I read "you have earned [negative number] reputation today", I read it with a sarcastic tone, and I *like* it. If you fixed the wording, then it would cease to sound sarcastic. It would even be better if it were 'Bravo [disparaging epithet]! You have *earned* [negative number] reputation today.'

Comment: @Louis However, I agree with Werner; gain can have a negative value, yet it keeps the sarcastic interpretation possible ;)

Comment: no! change should be in another direction, so that for positive rep changes, user would read: _"you **lost -30** reputation today"_ ([double negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative) FTW)

Comment: @gnat but doesn't "lost -30" mean "gained 30"? Same problem. You must mean "lost 30".

Comment: `gained` has a meaning closer to "possibly negative". For example in a game you might "gain" an illness debuff. It is hard to imagine you *earning* an illness. Recently I "earned" -10 rep because a user who had voted for me was deleted, and his/her votes were reversed. That is hardly something I "earned" - sarcastically or not. It wasn't my fault s/he was deleted. Maybe say "You **lost** 30 reputation today on Stack Overflow" with the bolding emphasising the word.

Comment: @NickGammon But you do "earn" -10 rep if you post a bad answer and 5 people downvote you. I think "earn" can be "possibly negative."

Comment: I think we might be thinking a little too hard about this. Is it really that important to change the one little word which easily fits in the sentence?

Comment: This is a variant of the pluralization bug requests.  I suggest you see a certain Jeff about a big S.

Comment: When I Googled "earn" the first definition was `gain deservedly in return for one's behaviour or achievements.`. I think negative rep excludes `deservedly` unless you mean `he deserved to be marked down`. I suggest most people think of `earn` as something positive. You earn a salary, you don't earn a tax. You wouldn't say "Hey, I earned -$1000 in tax today!".

Answer (score 8):

I prefer that the text stay the way it is. A negative sign stands out and makes it immediately noticeable that you *lost* reputation. Changing the word "earned" to "lost" is much less noticeable and I know that *I* would probably just assume that I really gained 30 rep that day.

Comment: even though it's red...?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ colorblind folk might not notice the red :)

Comment: Confusingly, every time someone upvotes this answer, I go check my inbox and I get a message that says "+10 You earned -30 reputation today"

Answer (score 3):

You didn't lose reputation. None of the previous votes which increase your reputation were taken away.  You *earned* negative votes:

```
earn: to merit as compensation, as for service; deserve:
```

Yes, there are other definitions of earn which only count *gains*, but the existence of those definitions doesn't preclude the use of the correct definition.

You *earned* those negative reputation points.  In the database rows were added with negative reputation, which were then *added* to your total reputation.

Whether your reputation increases or decreases is irrelevant.

Comment: I was just about to write something similar: "You earn downvotes just as much as you earn upvotes. You worked hard for that loss, enjoy it..."

Comment: But you don't always earn reputation loss. For example if someone upvotes your question then deletes your account, you lose reputation points. You don't deserve this, its just the way the dice fall..

Comment: @oxinabox alternately, you temporarily held rep you didn't initially deserve, and when they deleted, removed their invite, or otherwise, the undeserved rep was corrected. ;)

Comment: +1 I really liked the way you interpreted...

Answer (score 2):

Something that may not require not too much work

> Your reputation changed by X today

1. The phrase makes sense regardless of whether X is positive or negative.
2. I don't think that it has a sarcastic tone
3. It keeps the negative sign

Comment: Doesn't have the positive feeling of *earned*. Just use two words as in the proposal.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I agree about the positive feeling, but I was going for neutral as lost rep is not good. It would be nice to have a positive feeling for gained rep, but I wanted something that would not need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about reasons ones rep might decrease:
(Too long for a comment)

#### Downvotes by others, and Upvotes taken back:

You have **earned** this loss of rep through your failures.
You (theoretically) deserve it. Though it might not be so nice to point it out.

#### Downvoting others, and Posting Bounties

You have **spent/expended** rep.

#### User deleting account, Voting Fraud Reverted

You have **lost** the rep, it is misplaced, and go to you through quiet possibly no fault of your own.

---

I guess there is no single empathic verb.
**Changed** works though

Comment: My guess is that this case was probably because of  a bounty (50) + 2 answer upvotes (or 100+5....)

Answer (score -1):

One way for the site to neutrally impart the information and allow positive and negative values make sense:

*"Your Stack Overflow net reputation change for today: -30"*

Also, having the number at the end of the sentence seems clearer

Comment: Sounds too... official, in my opinion.

Comment: @shadowwizard maybe just use that for negative